# C# Problem with dependencies after copy and paste from another project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, dependencies, visual-studio-2019

I have a solution that was little unclean and I decided to create a repository to save it, I cloned the empty project from DevOps and pasted in this new folder only the code needed in order to push something clean.

I fixed all the paths and the dependencies to project of the new solution and I have a problem

**The project is .NetFramework 4.6.2**

[image: RestSharp with a warining]

[image: Warning I get in the ErrorList]

This doesn't happen only to one library but the only solution to have them work back again was to go to nuget.

The only way I have to get them working is from Nuget Package Manager finding the package:
removing and reinstalling.

Other attempts that I did:

- unload and reload all the project
- Restore Nuget Packages from the solution
- unload single project and reload with full dependency tree

Comment: I take it from my request:

"The only way I have to get them working is from Nuget Package Manager finding the package: removing and reinstalling."

If I do that everything is fine, the problem is that this happens to a lot of packages...

Comment: Thanks for the help :) That is a path that practically I did, but the problem I get is after the creation of the new project,
the problem is that most of the dependencies appears with a warning, with no more information of which I posted...

Comment: Can cleaning up the solution and rebuilding quickly complete the operation?

Comment: Tried but got no results....